# Counting the distance between 2 memory addresses

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, stack

I have the following 2 addresses and I want to count between them in order to learn how my stack looks like.

```
0xbffff947
```

and `0xbfffd56`

From gdb I m taking back the following

```
(gdb) print/x 0xbffff947 - 0xbfffd56
$24 = 0xb3fffbf1
```

But I want to know the exact number of bytes between these 2.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits, did you lose your monkey?

Comment: @Duck Lol.  My cover's been blown!

Comment: Why not just subtract them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing exactly the right thing, because

```
0xbffff947 - 0xbfffd56 = 0xb3fffbf1
```

(Note that he second operand has only 7 hex digits, so perhaps you did not
copy/paste the right memory address.)